# Getting the points from wglUseFontOutlines?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, opengl

I'm making a vector application for Windows. Right now i'm using wglUseFontOutlines to generate display lists which wrks well, except I would like to be able to let the user remodel the font. I would also like to use VBO's instead of DL's for this. Does Microsoft provide a way to get the points for this, or atleast the outlines, I could then use my tesselator to do the rest. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the Win32 API GetPath , it works really nice and it returns lines and bezier pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, `wglUseFontOutlines()` just does display lists.  You'll have to use [something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType) to get glyph outlines.